# Given $P(t): [0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ a space filling curve, can we calculate $\iint_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y) dxdy$ as $\int_0^1 f(P(t))\,dt$ or something alike?

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

Given $P(t): [0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ a continuous bijection, can we calculate $\iint_{[0,1]^2}f(x,y)\, dx\,dy$ as $\int_0^1 f(P(t))\,dt$ or something alike?

I'm thinking of the $P(t)$s as  peano curves: we know such continuous bijections exist, thus, with a single parameter $t$, we can fill up the entire domain of integration $D\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ and so, I'd think that we should be able to calculate the double integral in the title with a single integral (integrating with respect to $t$).

Is this possible?

E: As discussed in the comments of the only answer, there may be a few annoying technicalities here ($P$ not being a bijection), I'd rather not bother with them, but see if this idea is usable somehow.

I'm mostly interested in the Riemann or R-S integral, but related stuff about the lebesgue integral is also welcome.

Comment: @user251257 are you talking about the need of multiplying the integrand by "$P'(t)$" (and thus, saying what I want is not possible, because $P$ is not differentiable in at least countably infinitely many points)? If that's what you're saying, I believe this doesn't completely justify it: this is not a "normal" change of variables.

Comment: As mathguy says, there are no continuous bijections.  Peano curves are continuous and surjective but cannot be injective.

Comment: Someone on Wikipedia thinks that Wiener thinks it is somehow possible. There was no citation. See [Space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve?wprov=sfsi1)

Comment: That is probably what you looking for http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4549.pdf

Comment: @user251217 - That paper is about a different way to estimate double (or multiple) integrals - or even one-dimensional integrals. One way to estimate an integral is to choose a sequence of finite subsets of the integration domain, average the values of the function at those points, and multiply by the area (volume, etc.) of the domain. Or do some sort of weighted average, perhaps. The best choice of sampling points has them "random" and "equally spaced." The paper talks about Peano curves and similar ones for constructing such sets of sampling points, NOT for a change of variables to one dim.

Comment: To clarify: you have a SEQUENCE of quasi-random subsets; you compute an approximation of the integral for each such subset, and then you take the limit. They provide estimates of how good the set of sampling points is, and how good the approximations are.

Comment: @user251257 Wiener thinks it's possible? It certainly _is_ possible - the Hilbertt curve is more or less obviously measure-preserving.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I just cited what was stated in Wikipedia. There was no source given.

Comment: @user251257 A citation would be good. I'm no expert on Wiener, but I don't recall him saying anything about _continuous_ space-filling curves. In _The Fourier Integral and Certain of its Applications_ he does point out that there are _discontinuous_ space-filling maps with this property. In particular he points out that if $P$ is defined almost everywhere by the "obvious" trick with binary expansions, mapping $0.b_1b_2\dots$ to $(0,b_1,b_3\dots,0.b_2b_4\dots)$ then $P$ is measure-preserving.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I wasn't agreed nor disagreed with the claim that Wiener has said anything about that topic. I only repeated what was stated on Wikipedia (and explicitly said it wasn't my own opinion) in the hope that one might find something in that direction.

Comment: @user251257 You seem to be taking my replies to your comments as complaints about or criticisms of what you said. I don't know why. All you were doing was reporting on what Wikipedia says, fine. All I've been doing is trying to clarify the issues raised by what Wikipedia says here - I assumed you'd be interested.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Ah sorry. Then I have mistaken it.

Comment: @user251257 I looked it up - actually Wiener _does_ talk about continuous space-filling curves...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich oh thanks. Was it in some particular paper or book?

Comment: @user251257 _The Fourier Integral and Certain of its Applications_.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich thank you :D

Answer (score 9):

Well first, there is no continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]^2$. As of course has already been pointed out several times; your reply that you don't want to worry about that seems very curious - if you simply corrected the question to be something more sensible it would be a good question.

Anyway. Given a continuous surjection $P:[0,1]\to[0,1]^2$, is it true that $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dxdy=\int_0^1 f(P(t))\,dt?$$The answer is of course no for "most" such $P$, but it's yes for some $P$, including one of the standard examples - the answer is yes for the example commonly known as the [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve).

This says that the Hilbert curve $H$ is *measure-preserving*, which follows from the fact that $H^{-1}([j2^{-n},(j+1)2^{-n}]\times[k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}])$ is "essentially" (that is, except for a set of measure zero) equal to $[m4^{-n},(m+1)4^{-n}]$.

The Hilbert curve has other nice properties. For example, it's easy to see that a space-filling curve cannot be $Lip_\alpha$ for $\alpha>1/2$, and $H$ is in fact $Lip_{1/2}$. This says to me that $H$ is in some sense a very "efficient" space-filling curve; just as bad as needed to get the job done, no worse.

Answer (score 0):

Such $P(t)$ does not exist. If it did, it would be a homeomorphism (the inverse would also be continuous), since $[0,1]$ is compact and $[0,1]^2$ is separated. But the two are not homeomorphic; you can disconnect the line segment by removing a point, but you can't do the same to the square.

So the entire thing is philosophy about things that can't exist.

Comment: For change of variables you don't need injectivity  either. So that is a technical point...

Comment: OK, so it seems you want a different question than the one asked. Can we use Peano curves to reduce integrals over the square to integrals over the interval? Then the answer is "it depends" - on what kind of integral you mean. If you mean Lebesgue integral, then yes, in principle that is correct (but not with the formula provided).

Comment: I think that is the crucial/interesting point of the question, leaving the technical details aside.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Continuous functions are measurable, so the change of variables makes sense - but to use it, you need to be able to compute the one-dimensional measure of $P^{-1}(X)$ for measurable subsets $X$ of the square. No idea how to do that.

Comment: I think this use for numerical computations, as space filling curves are given by iterations and are not analytically available.

Comment: That's my point. I don't think it is possible to use this idea to compute integrals, even numerically (by approximation). You can't change variables over any of the (non-filling!) curves that converge to a Peano curve, so what's the approach?

Comment: Taking functions like the ones used on partitions of unity (of small support)  around a point of $(0,1)^2$, would likely suffice to prove that such $P$ cannot be used to that purpose.  Am I wrong?  Plus, one may move such functions around (i.e. if $f_0$ is such a function, then $f_0(x-a,y-b)$ has also small support and its support is still contained in $[0,1]^2$, for suitable values of $a,b$.)

Comment: @TheonAlexander Yes, you're wrong.